# How to convert wide data to long data

Tags: r

I now have a wide data as data, and I want to integrate it into a new data frame with columns named A,B,C. what should I do?

```
data<-data.frame(A1=c("a","b","c"),B1=c(1,2,3),C1=c(4,5,6),
       A2=c("d","e","f"),B2=c(7,8,9),C2=c(10,11,12),
       A3=c("g","h","j"),B3=c(13,14,15),C3=c(16,17,18))
```